# Last Used Cell in Worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need a formula *(not VBA)*  that will return the row number of the last used cell in a worksheet.

I have data like:

[image]

Not all columns have data and the columns are not filled with the same number of rows.

If I was dealing with only a single column *(say column **F**)*, I would use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MAX((ROW(Sheet1!F:F))*(Sheet1!F:F<>"")))
```

which yields *13*, but the data spans many columns in *Sheet1*

If I could use VBA rather than a formula, I would use something like:

```
Sub GetLastRow()
    Dim LastRow As Long, rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells
    LastRow = rng.Find(what:="*", after:=rng(1), searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    MsgBox LastRow
End Sub
```

I think I am missing something very simple.

Comment: Take a look: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm

Comment: @duDE  Thanks for responding....sadly, these solutions involve VBA

Comment: btw a non array formula type to find the last row in a specific column: `=MAX(IFERROR(MATCH("ZZZ",F:F),0),IFERROR(MATCH(1E +99,F:F),0))`

Comment: @ScottCraner  Thank you Scott...do you think a formula solution is possible ??  If it helps only the first 42 columns are populated.

Comment: Your sumproduct works: `=SUMPRODUCT(MAX((ROW(Sheet1!A:AP))*(Sheet1!A:AP<>"")))` it is slow so if you could limit the rows to the max possible it would help.

Comment: @ScottCraner  You are correct.....if you post an Answer, I'll accept.... **THANKS !**

Comment: Another: `=AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(A:AP)/(A:AP<>""),1)` again slow so if you could limit the rows it will be a lot quicker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use your SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MAX((ROW(Sheet1!A:AP))*(Sheet1!A:AP<>"")))
```

or this AGGREGATE:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(A:AP)/(A:AP<>""),1)
```

If you can limit the number of rows it will help speed up the formulas as they are array type formulas.

Comment: Thank you...while this may seem simple,...I was stumped for a non-VBA approach.